# Replace -inf, NaN and NA values with zero in a dataset in R

Tags: r, time-series, nan, zoo

I am trying to run some trading strategies in R. I have downloaded some stock prices and calculated returns. The new return dataset has a number of -inf, NaN, and NA values. I am reproducing a row of the dataset (log_ret). Its a zoo dataset.

```
library(zoo)
log_ret <- structure(
  c(0.234,-0.012,-Inf,NaN,0.454,Inf), .Dim = c(1L, 6L), 
  .Dimnames = list(NULL, c("x", "y", "z", "s", "p", "t")),
  index = structure(12784, class = "Date"),
  class = "zoo"
)

               x      y    z   s     p   t
2005-01-01 0.234 -0.012 -Inf NaN 0.454 Inf
```

How can I replace these unwanted values with 0?

Comment: https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/is.finite.html

Answer (score 26, accepted):

As per `?zoo`:

> Subscripting by a zoo object whose data contains
>        logical values is undefined.

So you need to wrap the subsetting in a `which` call:

```
log_ret[which(!is.finite(log_ret))] <- 0
log_ret
               x      y z s     p t
2005-01-01 0.234 -0.012 0 0 0.454 0
```

Answer (score 28):

`Inf`, `NA` and `NaN` are matched by `!is.finite`, for example

```
a <- c(1, Inf, NA, NaN)
a[!is.finite(a)] <- 0
# a is now [1, 0, 0, 0]
```

I don't know too much about manipulating `zoo` objects, but for the example above

```
log_ret[1, !is.finite(log_ret)] <- 0
```

works. In your actual data you will have to loop over all rows. There might be a `zoo`-specific way of doing this.

**Edit:** The zoo-specific way is `log_ret[which(!is.finite(log_ret))] <- 0`.

Comment: I tried that before as well. But for some reason, none of the values in the dataset changed.

Comment: make sure you don't confuse `is.finite()` and `is.infinite()`

Answer (score 18):

Another way to do it is (where df=your dataframe):

```
is.na(df)<-sapply(df, is.infinite)
df[is.na(df)]<-0
```

I don't know if this works for zoo objects, but it gets around the problem of is.infinite() only working on vectors.

Comment: `log_ret` in the question is NOT a data.frame.  This code gives an error if df is `log_ret`.

Comment: @Grubbmeister  does the first line set all infinite values to NA and then the second line replaces all NA with 0? if yes, is the first step creating a logical vector is.na(df) that gets stored in R?

Comment: @Din no it sets all infinites values to na, then all nas to 0

Answer (score 7):

Using mutate_all in dplyr:

```
library(dplyr)
fortify.zoo(log_ret) %>% mutate_all(function(x) ifelse(is.infinite(x), 0, x))
```

Comment: That code gives an error: `Error in UseMethod("tbl_vars") : no applicable method for 'tbl_vars' applied to an object of class "zoo"`

Comment: That no longer gives an error but it gives a data frame whereas a zoo object is wanted.

Answer (score 5):

Since the lifecycle for `mutate_all` has been superseded by the use of `across`:

```
library(dplyr)
fortify.zoo(log_ret) %>% mutate(across(.cols = everything(), ~ ifelse(is.infinite(.x), 0, .x)))
```